# Making MinIO bucket prefix read-only via policy

Tags: minio

I have a MinIO bucket containing objects prefixed by the year.  I would like to make previous years read-only across all users.  It seems the ideal would be to set a bucket access policy, and I tried the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::hls/2020/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::hls/2021/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::hls/2022/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This didn't work, meaning I could still upload new objects with a `2020/` prefix.  I thought a `Deny` in the bucket policy would take precedence over the user (IAM) policy, but it seems not.
The user policy in this case follows:

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": [
    "s3:CreateBucket",
    "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListBucket",
    "s3:PutObject"
   ],
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::hls",
    "arn:aws:s3:::hls/*",
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Is there a way to craft a bucket policy which results in certain prefixes becoming read-only across all users?

If not, is there another way to achieve the goal?  I also considered:

- Putting a "legal hold" on the prior years.  This seems to operate at the object level and I've got hundreds of thousands of objects for each year, so it becomes rather intensive.  (My bucket wasn't created with locking so I'd also have to set up a new bucket for this.)
- Denying write access at the user level.  OK, but I'd have to adjust each user/access key.